# Using ffmpeg how can I convert dv pal format to mp4 without interlacing issues?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have imported PAL DV. When trying this

```
ffmpeg -i my_video.dv output.mp4
```

I get interlacing issues.. So I need to deinterlace the input somehow...

Comment: Let me quote: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**"

Comment: isn't ffmpeg used primarily for programming?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This did the trick!

```
ffmpeg -i my_video.dv -vf yadif output.mp4
```

Comment: you should accept this as the correct answer

Comment: yes, I have to wait two days, silly stackoverflow